# Raspberry Pi Auto-start Executable with Systemd, Loaded but Inactive (Dead)

Tags: pi-4, c++, systemd, systemd-startup

I am trying to run a CPP client application to connect to a server when Raspberry Pi is booted and connected to the Internet. I validated this CPP executable (Asio_Client_Main) works fine when manually run in the terminal. (pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ./Asio_Client_Main - Once connected, it sends a message to a server.)

First time to use **Systemd**, and this is what I did.

1. made **client_test_a.service** and copied it to **/etc/systemd/system/**

```
[Unit]
Description=Client Test A
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/Asio_Client_Main

StandardOutput=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. **sudo systemctl start client_test_a.service**
3. **sudo systemctl status client_test_a.service**

```
● client_test_a.service - Client Test A
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/client_test_a.service; enabled; vendor pr
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2021-02-07 18:00:02 EST; 10min ago
  Process: 1586 ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/Asio_Client_Main (code=exited, status
 Main PID: 1586 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 07 18:00:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Client Test A.
Feb 07 18:00:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: client_test_a.service: Succeeded.
```

4. **sudo systemctl enable client_test_a.service**

It's **loaded but inactive**. I think it's just exited, but how can I keep it connected?
I also don't think it's connected to the server because I don't see any client connection on the server-side. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried **Type=oneshot**. Using RPi 4 B with wifi connection.

**Main Cpp Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Asio_Client.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> lunarPixel;
    
    std::ifstream file("LunarPixel.txt");
    std::string str;

    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        // Process str
        std::vector<int> result;
        std::istringstream iss(str);

        for (std::string str; iss >> str;)
        {
            result.push_back(std::stoi(str));
        }

        lunarPixel.push_back(result);
    }

    auto& lunar_time = lunar_timer::Init();
    lunar_time.set_lunar_pixel(lunarPixel);

    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    try
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> lunarPixel;

        std::ifstream file("LunarPixel.txt");
        std::string str;

        while (std::getline(file, str))
        {
            // Process str
            std::vector<int> result;
            std::istringstream iss(str);

            for (std::string str; iss >> str;)
            {
                result.push_back(std::stoi(str));
            }

            lunarPixel.push_back(result);
        }

        auto& lunar_time = lunar_timer::Init();
        lunar_time.set_lunar_pixel(lunarPixel);

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);

        const std::string ipAddress = "192.***.*.*"; //ip
        const std::string portNum = "2120";

        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(ipAddress, portNum);
        chat_client c(io_context, endpoints, lunar_time);

        std::thread t([&io_context]() { io_context.run(); });

        char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
        
        std::cout << "Before_ while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))" << std::endl; 

        while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
        {
            chat_message msg;
            msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
            std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
            msg.encode_header();
            c.write(msg);
        }

        std::cout << "Exited" << std::endl;  

        c.close();
        t.join();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2/9/2021:**

**Prints before and after While Loop**
Please see the Main.cpp Above to see the complete code

```
std::cout << "Before_ while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))" << std::endl; 

while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
{
    chat_message msg;
    msg.body_length(std::strlen(line));
    std::memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
    msg.encode_header();
    c.write(msg);
}

std::cout << "Exited" << std::endl;
```

I also used a bash script instead of executing the program directly.

**mystartup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Store first parameter in a variable, which should be the log file location.
LOG_FILE="$1"
# Set a default log file location if the parameter was empty, i.e. not specified.
if [ -z "$LOG_FILE" ]
then
  LOG_FILE="/var/log/testlog.txt"
fi

cd /home/pi/Desktop
./Asio_Client_Main
```

Then

sudo systemctl start client_test_a.service
sudo systemctl status client_test_a.service

```
● client_test_a.service - Client Test A
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/client_test_a.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-02-09 23:09:58 EST; 3s ago
  Process: 2004 ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/mystartup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2004 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 09 23:09:58 raspberrypi bash[2004]: Before_ while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
Feb 09 23:09:58 raspberrypi bash[2004]: Exited
Feb 09 23:09:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: client_test_a.service: Succeeded.
Feb 09 23:09:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Client Test A.
```

So when I ran the program, it does not exit the loop. But when using systemd, it just exits the loop without taking user inputs. How can I keep running in the foreground taking user inputs?

Comment: Does the program, executed from the command line, run short and finished successfully, or does it stay running until you kill it for example with Ctrl-C?

Comment: @Ingo It stays connected until I kill it.

Comment: you ask `how can I keep it connected?` ... but your comment states `It stays connected` ... so is the process running or not? Also, can you describe what `Asio_Client_Main` does on startup, as in, does it fork off a new process that runs as a daemon for example? Also, is it supposed to run as root?

Comment: @JaromandaX It stays connected when I run it in a command line (It's compiled and executed properly that way.) I want it to automatically run on startup. I don't think it's ever properly executed making a connection to the server with Systemd.

Comment: oh, right, misunderstood - does it run in the background or foreground when you start it like `./Asio_Client_Main`

Comment: @JaromandaX I am pretty new to all these... Might be better to explain what I want to do here. This is a LED matrix running off of Pi 4 which I want to communicate with the server so that the user can control the led with the socket connection. User Socket Client <-> Socket Server <-> LED Matrix Socket Client - When the LED turned on, it automatically sends a status of the "animation" it's displaying. This LED client socket runs asynchronously. I don't care if it's supposed to be a root or not as long as it does the job. Sorry if it's unclear. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: all I want to know is ... when you run `./Asio_Client_Main` does it run in the background or foreground

Comment: @JaromandaX Once it's run, it runs I guess as background since there is no more interaction or interface. But eventually, I want it to receive the command through a server connection and call a function to display different things on the LED matrix.

Comment: how does it go into background? does it fork a new process? that's why systemd thinks it completes, because the process systemd starts does complete

Comment: @JaromandaX I added the main cpp code to the post. I didn't do anything to run it in the background through a forking or anything. So it could run foreground. But since I am simply modifying this boost asio chat example (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp) it might do something to go in the background which I cannot identify...

Comment: you can tell if it runs in foreground or background very easily ... when you run it, does the command prompt come back while the program is running? If so, it's running in background, if not, it's running in foreground - don't need to see code to determine that

Comment: @JaromandaX The command prompt does not come back. So it's running foreground... Then what's the cause of this exit.. Is there something to do with the text file I have in the working directory? I am reading this LunarPixel.txt which is in the same directory of the executable (/home/pi/Desktop) Should I link it somewhere in systemd?

Comment: That's only an issue if it *needs* to run in foreground (see my comment on Ingo's answer).  *"I think it's just exited"* -> Whether that's true or not is something you need to **know** in order to approach this problem correctly.  And that is pretty easy -- write the PID to a file or just look for the process by name with `ps -C`.  **And log something. Log lots of things.**  Your error handling is to stderr, which may or may not get captured in the journal log.  You should either explicitly write a file or use the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` options in `man systemd.exec`.

Answer (score 3):

From the status as shown everything seems OK so far. It shows that the program has run and finished successfully with `code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS`. No problems seen by systemd. I  did not understand the program at a glance, and didn't take the effort to analyze it. Does this program has some exit points in case of an error? If so, then exit there with exit code 1. this will cause systemd to terminate the service with an error, and you will know it does not run successfully. A `printf` with an error message is also useful there. You will find these messages in the systemd journal, shown with `journalctl`.

If it runs in the foreground on the command line, it is OK. Don't change it. Systemd will manage to run it as service in the background with full control about it. So the service must run until you stop it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop client_test_a.service
```

I assume you are running it on the command line as user **pi**. So I suggest to try it also with the Unit. To summarize it I would use this Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Client Test A
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Desktop
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/Asio_Client_Main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It is important that the program runs until you stop it with systemctl, or until it terminates with an error/exit code greater than 0.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks a lot. It really helped to find the problem. It looks like the problem is the While loop that's taking a user input. (Please see the updated section in the post.) When running the program, it stays in the loop. But when running through systemd, it just exits. How can I keep it running in the foreground and taking user inputs?

Comment: I also tried Type=simple instead of oneshot. Still just exting

Comment: @mqmarathon Systemd is made to start programs as silent services in the background. It isn't made for user interaction. This will break its intended working and service management. Forget it.